posX cannot be resolved or is not a field
I was using a self implemented Linked List on processing and that error just happened:
posX cannot be resolved or is not a field
Here's my code:
Main Class:

List<Garbage> GarbageList = new List<>();

void removeGarbage(int x,int y){
  if(GarbageList.head != null && GarbageList.head.data.posX==x && GarbageList.head.data.posY==y){
    GarbageList.head = GarbageList.head.head;
  } else{
    Node end = GarbageList.head;
      while (end.next != null) {
        if(end.next.data.posX==x && end.next.data.posY==y){
          if(end.next.next != null){
            end.next = end.next.next;
          } else{
            end.next = null;
          }
        }
        end = end.next;
      }
  }
}



Garbage Class:

class Garbage{
  
  int type;
  int value;
  int posX, posY;
  PImage sprite;

/methods
.
.
.
  
}



Node Class:
class Node<T> {
  T data;
  Node next;

  Node(T data) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = null;
  }
}


List Class:

class List<T> {
  Node<T> head;

  void add(T data) {
    Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);
    if (head == null) {
      head = newNode;
    } else {
      Node end = head;
      while (end.next != null) {
        end = end.next;
      }
      end.next = newNode;
    }
  }

}

I was trying to create a function to remove a Garbage based on its X and Y position for a future implementation but it happened to not work

The system requests that you add non-code details for a reason. You are much less likely to get a satisfactory answer if you don't fully explain what problem you are trying to solve. Or perhaps more importantly, people are much less likely to want to help you with your problem if you don't make an attempt explain your issue in an approachable manor.

I think there's a small typo in your code. In the removeGarbage method you have a typo in the condition if(end.next.next =! null). It should be if(end.next.next != null) instead of =!. This typo is causing a problem understanding what are posX and posY as fields within the class.
if (end.next.next != null) {

Also, you might want to ensure that GarbageList.head is not null before accessing its properties to avoid potential NullPointerExceptions
if (GarbageList.head != null && GarbageList.head.data.posX == x && GarbageList.head.data.posY == y) {


Oh thanks I havent noticed the misstype, and it is also nice to test whether the head is null. Anyways, the same error keep happening

Nevermind. I solve it. For those who are interested in knowing the answer, my error was declaring the node end without using Garbage
What i should have done is:
Node<Garbage> end = GarbageList.head;
instead of:
Node end = GarbageList.head;
in line 7 from main
